# Errors with initialization of an unordered_map inside of a class

Tags: c++, simulation, unordered-map

The error I'm getting is `Exception thrown at 0x00007FF77339C476 in VirusSimulator.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF.`

I've gone through my code with Visual Studio's debugger, and it seems like the error is from an attempt to call .size() on a unordered map of class objects. 
Specifically, in the implementation of "list":

```
size_type size() const _NOEXCEPT
    {   // return length of sequence
    return (this->_Mysize());
    }
```

When stepping through with the debugger and keeping an eye on local variables, I see: `this 0xccccccccccccce0c folders={ size=??? }`
(folders being the map of class variables)
Just below is a section of int main() where I manually initialize a default folder in each computer's drive's map of folders:

```
vector<Computer> macs;

    for (int i = 0; i < mac_amount; i++)
    {
        macs.push_back(Computer(OSX)); //Initialize a computer with an operating system
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < macs.size(); i++)
    {
        //... Here is some code initializing connections between the computer objects

        //and here is the manual insert of folders into the map
        macs[i].getDrive()->addFolder("default"); //This used to be in the computers constructor but I moved it out here for testing
    }
```

definition of addFolder:

```
void Harddrive::addFolder(string name)
{
Folder new_folder;
new_folder.set_name(name);
folders.insert(std::pair<string, Folder>(name, new_folder));
}
```

Basically, a random computer object then runs a virus that attempts to install itself to every other connected computer object by accessing the list of connections that is has, which contain pointers to the other computer objects.
It then de-references these and attempts to find the default folder on each respective computer's harddrive, but then fails to do so, claiming that the folder is uninitialized?

If any other pieces of my code are needed, then the full code can be found at https://github.com/BananaSky/VirusSimulator/tree/UnstableNetworkAdditions
Most of the code I've already tested for bugs, and that's why I've only posted such a small portion.

Any help is much appreciated!! (But also, it's getting late here and I might be going to sleep soon, so I apologize if I can't respond right away)

`--ALSO: Please note that this is just a simulation and that I'm not actually intending to create any form of computer virus.`

Here is the section of code where the error occurs (inside Virus.cpp):

```
vector<int> vulnerableConnectionIPs = installedOn->getNetworkAdapter()->getConnection()->getConnections();

    for (int i = 0; i < vulnerableConnectionIPs.size(); i++)
    {
        Computer* accessRequest = installedOn->getNetworkAdapter()->getConnection()->getConnect(vulnerableConnectionIPs[i])->giveAccess();
        if (accessRequest != NULL && accessRequest != installedOn)
        {
            if (accessRequest->getDrive()->getFolders()) //Error occurs here
            {
                accessRequest->Install(this, "default"); //Infect if infectable :)
            }
            else
            {
                cout << "No folders exist on " << accessRequest->getDrive()->getModel() << endl;
            }
        }
    }
```

**I'm working on replicating this on a smaller scale, and I'll probably get that posted by tomorrow**

Comment: Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I've tried replicating this but I've been unable to reproduce the same error. I'll see what I can do though

Comment: I scanned through your code. It looks you are creating a library. Without a driver program it's nearly impossible to tell what the execution order is to see what the offending code is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A memory address of `0xcccccccccccccccc` (64-bit) or `0xcccccccc` (32-bit) is Visual Studio's way of denoting an `uninitialized block of memory`. There's also `0xfeeefeee` for already free'd and `0x00000000` for a null pointer.

Check that you have actually stored a value in the variable you are trying to access.

The values actually shown from error dialogs may be offset to values **close** to the above locations, you'll just have to trace through the program.

Your initial description of the error also points to at least trying to de-reference a null pointer.

More code would be helpful.

Comment: Thanks for this. It really helped me when I was looking through the debugger for what wasn't being initialized.